# Use Date.js parse method not for the current date

Tags: javascript, date, nlp, sugar.js

I want to use a javascript library(like Date.js) to parse natural language expressions such as "next tuesday" or "tommorow" but it seems that it evaluates the expression based on current date for example:

Given today's date is: Mon Mar 09 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)

Input: Date.parse('next tuesday');

Output: Tue Mar 10 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)

I would like to parse the expression "next tuesday" given a specific date. Is there a way how one can achieve this using date.js or any other Javascript Library(I tried sugarjs too)? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Set today to the date you want to have and make your parse.

https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#set

Probably read the API before asking this question.

Comment: Didn't work:

> Date.today().set({
    millisecond: 500,
    second: 30,
    minute: 45,
    hour: 18,
    day: 15,
    month: 6,
    year: 2008
    });
< Tue Jul 15 2008 18:45:30 GMT+0200 (CEST)
> Date.parse('next wednesday');
< Wed Mar 11 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)

Comment: Interesting...looks like the library is not designed to do that :-/

Comment: Do you know any other library that has this feature?

Comment: Well I just looked into the Date.js Script itself, and it seems like the parse function has a variable hard coded "var today = Date.today()" from which the parser calculates the "next wednesday". If you change that hard coded variable to another date Date.parse("next wednesday") will return the next wednesday from that date on. It should be easy to make that variable a parameter of the parse function so you can have the behaviour you want.